# sed insert newline after match

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable with following content:

```
k1065-betfirst-4ccc6a2cf196 (192.168.255.46) is off-line k1164-betfirst-4ccc6a8ff0be (192.168.255.54) is off-line K1165-BetFirst-4ccc6a2cf343 (192.168.255.26) is off-line K1185-BetFirst-4ccc6aba7af7 (192.168.255.18) is off-line k1331-betfirst-448a5bb71eb8 (192.168.255.38) is off-line
```

I need to insert after "line" linebreak. In order to do this, I use sed:

```
echo -e $mailbody | sed 's/line/\n&/g' | tee -a hosts2.txt
```

But it insert newline before "line":

```
 k1065-betfirst-4ccc6a2cf196 (192.168.255.46) is off-
line k1164-betfirst-4ccc6a8ff0be (192.168.255.54) is off-
line K1165-BetFirst-4ccc6a2cf343 (192.168.255.26) is off-
line K1185-BetFirst-4ccc6aba7af7 (192.168.255.18) is off-
line k1331-betfirst-448a5bb71eb8 (192.168.255.38) is off-
line
```

Can anyone give me a hint, how to rewrite sed, to write newline after "line"?

Comment: So, swap `\n` and `&`? `sed 's/line/&\n/g'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping the `&` and `\n`. Also, you might need to remove the space after `line`:

```
's/line */&\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

c.f. [this resource](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) for lots of good examples. e.g.:

```
# insert a blank line below every line which matches "regex"
sed '/regex/G'
```

Comment: Note - this might not be exactly what was intended... but the resource is still good, as is [this one](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Answer (score 0):

In BSD/macOS `sed`, a literal newline with `\`-escape must be used:

```
's/line */\
/g'
```